# How to create an SVN pre-commit hook to unzip a file into a directory before commiting to the repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, batch-file

I am using MySql Workbench, which stores files using a proprietary format which it turns out is simply a renamed zip file.

I would like the unzipped contents to be placed in my repository on commit.

Is it possible to have SVN run a batch file to unzip the contents before comitting to the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using TortiseSVN or just commiting via the command line? If it's just via the command line, then you can trivially write the batch file to do the unzipping yourself, and call that instead. If you're using TortiseSVN, then I don't think you can do it. (You're looking for a client-side hook, not a hook at the repo level ..., well, at least that's what I think).